# show long number in format number in blade laravel

Tags: laravel

I have number like this:
2,800,000,000 billion
and I want show it like this 2.8 billion
I try this

```
{{rtrim($amounts,0)}}
```

but its show 28 billion and its not correct

how can write this in blade laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do it just like below

```
$number = 2800000000;
$formatted = number_format($number / 1000000000, 1, '.', '') . ' billion';

echo $formatted; // Output: 2.8 billion
```

for your specific case it could be something like this

```
{{number_format($amounts / 1000000000, 1, '.', '')}}
```